# Display item Listview in Toast

Tags: listview, click, toast

I wish to display value item inside a toast when i click on it. how to do ?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements Callback {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BDDRequest.GetRequest(this, SendData.getUserTest(), this);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listrequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) {
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(response.split("comClient")));
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        //Show fallback message here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mylist.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
})
```